# Spark submit fail on call setEntityResolver of XMLConfiguration on Apache Common Configuration

Tags: apache-spark, submit

I have a  problem when i try to submit my application with spark submit command:

```
/bin/spark-submit --class MyClass myjar.jar
```

I set master url programmatically.

I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.setEntityResolver(Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;)V
```

when i run my program on IDE all work correctly. This problem does not arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the cause of the problem.

Spark use hadoop-client-2.2.0 that use hadoop-common that use common-configuration-1.6.

In my application I used common-configuration-v1.10 where `XMLConfiguration.setEntityResolver` is implemented. Instead in version 1.6 of the library that method is not present.

When i run:

```
/bin/spark-submit --class MyClass myjar.jar
```

XMLConfiguration.class of common-configuration-v1.6 is loaded and the JVM does not find the method `setEntityResolver`

I have resolved using common-configuration-v2.0-beta1 in my application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the jar you are submitting may not have all of the dependencies it requires in it. The solution to this is to build an assembly jar, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html (for maven), or https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly (for sbt).

Comment: I have creare a jar with dependency before submit it to spark